# Differences between Project Dependencies vs Content Roots to access files from another project in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

As far as I understand, a PyCharm project (ProjectA) can access modules/files from another project (ProjectB) in a couple of different ways:

1. Attach ProjectB to ProjectA using the File>Open>Attach menu.  The relationship is managed via the File>Settings>Project:ProjectA>Project Dependencies menu item.
   OR,
2. From within ProjectA, via File>Settings>Project:ProjectA>Project Structure>+Add Content Root.  This adds ProjectB as a subdirectory in ProjectA.

I have a particular project (module library) that I share between multiple projects.  What are the issues to consider in choosing one of the options over the other?

I can't see anything in the documentation (or on SO) that compares the two, so perhaps the options perform quite differently and can't be considered alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First ask yourself what a **Project** is in PyCharm?

Basically each **Project** is an `.idea` folder that the IDE creates and manages for you:

> [**Project settings**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/setting-up-your-project.html#settings)
>
> Project settings apply to the current project only. They are stored together with other project files in the `.idea` directory in the `.xml` format.

#### So what's the difference between using "Project Dependencies" and "Content Root" (and what do they have in common?):

##### 1. Using "Project Dependencies":

> 1. Attach ProjectB to ProjectA using the File>Open>**Attach menu**. The relationship is managed via the File>Settings>Project:ProjectA>**Project Dependencies** menu item.

The first difference is that you'll have a full **Project**. It will show as a top level item in [Project Tool Window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-tool-window.html); and it will be linked in `.idea/modules.xml` as:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="ProjectModuleManager">
    <modules>
      <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/.idea/Your_Main_Project.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/.idea/Your_Main_Project.iml" />
      <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/../Your_Dependency_project/.idea/Your_Dependency_Project.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/../Your_Dependency_Project/.idea/Your_Dependency_Project.iml" />
    </modules>
  </component>
</project>
```

All the functionalities the IDE makes available for one **Project** are also available for the other, because both are **Project**s.

##### 2. Using "Project Structure" > "Add Content Root":

If you add a single path as a "Content Root" directory the IDE will add a single line in the `.idea/Your_Main_Project.iml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="PYTHON_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager">
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../Your_Dependency_Project" />
  </component>
</module>
```

##### 3. What do they have in common?

The only thing both options have in common is adding the selected directory to the [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonpath#envvar-PYTHONPATH). If all you're interested in is having the main project find the source files using "Add Content Root" is enough. If on the other hand you want to navigate and have the IDE manage that dependency as a complete project then choose "Project Dependencies".

Comment: Great answer; but I might ask another iteration in response to your last paragraph, what would be the reasons for wanting the IDE to 'manage that dependency as a complete project' vs just having access to the source files?  not sure I full understand the significance of what you've said there.

Comment: @DavidWalker try the ["attach project" option](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/open-projects.html#daa8c6c8) and see the difference. Having a "project dependency" makes PyCharm check at startup that those projects are properly configured. If they aren't (for whatever reason a project's `.idea` is broken or the project is missing or misconfigured) the IDE warns you. If you only have a contents root the only warning you might get (before run-time) is that the directory isn't there. In the "dependcy" option the `.idea` is checked for internal consistency.